# Nesting two spring models

Tags: java, spring-boot, model, nested

i try to nest two models, so my response should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "some_name",
    "value": ["value1", "value2"],
    "details": {
        "name": "Test name",
        "surname": "Test surname",
        "phone": "Test phone",
        "email": "Test email"
    }
}
```

I have working CRUD MongoDB API, but something is not right here. I have null for "details" in controller.

An object: com.user.model.User@7fe8380d[_id=null,name=some_name,value=[value1, value2],details=null]

Let me show you what I have done so far:

### CONTROLLER:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/someaction")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService service;

    public UserController(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("An object: " + ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(user));
        return service.createUser(user);
    }

}
```

### SERVICE:

```
import com.inpost.user_registration.repository.UserRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public User createUser(User user) {
        user.set_id(ObjectId.get());
        repository.save(user);
        return user;
    }

}
```

### REPOSITORY:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    User findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
}
```

### MODEL for "Details":

```
public class Details {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public Details() {
    }

    public Details(String name, String surname, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
   }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Details [_id=" + name + ", env=" + surname + ", services=" + phone + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

### MODEL for "User":

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User {

    @Id
    public ObjectId _id;
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<String> value;
    public Details details;

    public User() {}

    public User(ObjectId _id, String name, ArrayList<String> value, Details details) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        return _id.toHexString();
    }

    public void set_id(ObjectId _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(ArrayList<String> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [_id=" + _id + ", name=" + name + ", value=" + value + ", details=" + details + "]";
    }

}
```

Now everything works fine when i try to save "name" and "value".
When i try to post with "details" I get null

```
{
    "_id": "5c4c5c3f7a56c12578122d73",
    "name": "some_name",
    "value": [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ],
    "details": null
}
```

Anyone can help me with that ? Somewhere I skip something important.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to either specifically call save on Details entity or annotate it with CascadeType.ALL to accomplish automatic persisting of details entity when User entity is persisted.